# Proton Decay; How long until this becomes a problem and are there ways to overcome it?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, universe, proton-decay

I've long wondered about the future of our species. Taking the long view,  I find it very amusing to consider the challenges that humans will face and (hopefully) overcome on our journey to the end of time. The most vexing problem is the apparently insurmountable issue of Proton Decay and how this could put a premature halt to our species and in fact any complex baryonic structures. I know that Proton Decay has not been observed in practice, but the timescales involved for the effects to become appreciable have not and will not for a great long while elapse(d).  The only possible solution I've been able to come up with is Anthropo-nucleosynthesis (this is the only term I could think of meaning "human caused matter generation" but maybe there already is a word/phrase for it that I am unaware of). That would only be effective if these newly forged protons/neutrons would have the same lifespan as those that were created from Big Bang nucleosynthesis. Anyways, I know this was a very long winded intro question/statement, but I'm curious as to your thoughts, solutions, refinements, or problems with anything I've laid out here. What do you think?

Comment: And to clarify, I've read that the predicted half-life of a Proton is 10(31) to 10(36) years.

Comment: Then we  are in trouble.

Comment: @CountTo10 I know it's a laughably long time,  but if people are still around then (and I hope they will be) then they really are in some deep s#it. Think how awful that would be....

Comment: The proton decay is at least $10^{34}$ years long, but in around $10^{11}$ years, there won't be stars anymore...

Comment: @peterh We're already at 10^11 (ish) years though, aren't we?

Comment: @peterh And also,  it's thought that some red dwarfs can live as long as tens of trillions of years. So if the last star that is more and happens to be a red dwarf comma then it will live for an extraordinarily long time..

Comment: @PhillippeGreenough Yes, and there could be special, rare circumstances (f.e. collision of black dwarfs) which could result to new stars even after that.

Comment: @PhillippeGreenough The proton decay requires a virtual particle in the order of $10^{16} GeV$ to exist, for a short time described by the uncertainity principle. This was tested until around $10^3 GeV$, so I am not sure it can be extrapolated so naively by 13 zeroes.

Comment: @peterh I was under the impression that Proton Decay has not been observed at all. If I'm mistaken, please correct me but you said "this was tested until around..." and there is no way to test Proton Decay experimentally or  in any of the literature I have ever come across.

Comment: @PhillippeGreenough It wasn't observed, I didn't wrote that it had been, maybe you misunderstood something.

Comment: Did you read the entire post I made prior to this?

Comment: Even if protons do decay (the standard model of physics says they don't), this is a non-problem for the next $10^31$ years. It is not our problem. It is not our children's problem. It is not our children's children's ... children's problem. This is not a good question for this particular corner of the stackexchange network.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no problem for organized matter if protons decay. Humans and all structures depend on the table of elements, and the elements in the human body,  [as seen in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclide#Nuclear_properties_and_stability) ,all have isotopes that decay and many of them exist in the human body with the exchange processes that keep us alive. The lifetimes of the isotopes vary,   [Continually some isotopes in the body decay](http://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/faqs/faqradbods.html) and the race is surviving.

The [limit of the proton decay lifetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Experimental_evidence) assures us that if a proton decays from the human body, the human would be dead by biological laws before even theoretically a second proton would decay. The human body has [avogadro numbers multiples of protons.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) .

So no problem at the end of times from proton decays, though there will certainly be a host of problems for humans, depending on the model.

Comment: What I was referring to was more the fact that baryons will decay into more fundamental fermions that make them up. Not alpha or beta Decay but an as yet unseen form of decay in which the proton can no longer hold itself together. And given the time skills involved this would be the most common form of matter at that point.

Comment: Considering the number of baryons and the long lifetime of the proton a lot more will have happened to humans before this, depending on the model. The big bang does not need proton decay to dissolve life  and it will happen long before protons decay .

Comment: I know, I was only entertaining the thought of how that problem might be dealt with by our far descendants (if they still exist at all).

Comment: And what do you mean by "the big bang does not need...."  I'm confused as to your use of the Big Bang in this discussion since that was a very short period of time that ended 13.6 ish billion years ago.

Comment: Look at the BB model prediction for the end of times https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang#/media/File:CMB_Timeline300_no_WMAP.jpg . Everything will be distancing from everything else, in the end humans will not be able to exist  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe . It depends on the model but certainly there will be many more problems for survival of the species before proton decay becomes a problem

Comment: yes but the timescales involved seem to point to proton decay being an issue much sooner than a big rip type scenario.

Comment: Link? it will alldepend on assumptions of constants

Comment: I don't have the links now cus I'm on my phone,  not my computer. Last time I was looking into it, the big rip won't shrink every atom's particle horizon to its own electron shell until about 10^40 years where as proton decay will reach appreciable effect in 10^31-10^36 years. I can send you links to my references tomorrow when I have my computer. Those numbers I listed here are from memory and so they might be a little off. I'll check it tomorrow and then send the links your way.